# Granting permissions on Redshift system tables to non-superusers

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

A non-superuser needs to get permission to execute catalog queries on certain system tables in a Redshift DB (multiple schemas) as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_join_PG_examples.html.

What the user should be able to do is see all schemas, tables and columns within a database, in order to essentially tell if the `modified_date` column of each table, has been updated in the daily ETL.

Looking at documentation, it looks like setting `alter user SYSLOG ACCESS UNRESTRICTED` as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_visibility-of-data.html looks like an option, is it sufficient?

Or perhaps I can do `grant all on pg_catalog.pg_class to user` and so forth for all the necessary system tables mentioned above?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SYSLOG ACCESS UNRESTRICTED will allow your user to query all the system catalog tables, but for some system tables like [PG_TABLE_DEF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html) they may also need to ensure that their [search_path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html) includes the schemas they are interested in.

Comment: It looks like the user needs to have access to the schema as well.